# I am facing the below error in grunt

Tags: javascript, build, gruntjs, min, jshint

If I type the *grunt* the following error is displaying:

```
Fatal error: Different sources attempting to write to the same destination:
 {
    "dest": "dist\\scripts\\dynamic-form\\dynamic-form.min.js",
    "src": [
        "app\\scripts\\dynamic-form\\dynamic-form.min.js"
    ]
}
  {
    "files": []
}
```

Comment: Can anyone please help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that `styles/vendor.css`, as required by `login.pt` and `index.pt` have
the same resources.

Answer (score 0):

i just configure in my grunt file.js as shown below

```
{
  "dist\\scripts\\dynamic-form\\dynamic-form.min.js": [
        "app\\scripts\\dynamic-form\\dynamic-form.min.js"]
}
```